# Featured Image .svg height and width 1px only

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, svg

I need to create a **custom type post** where will be added the name of the client and its logo.
The logo will be added as a Featured Image. But the problem is that WordPress does not recognize the SVG size.

[image]

What is an alternative fixing that? I tried to modify the CSS but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was quite simple ... just be sure that the height and width are set inside the svg code, like: `<svg height="100" viewBox="0 0 50 50" width="100">`